# What does 4X, 5X, 6X VALUE! mean in Special Offers in CoC?

Tags: clash-of-clans

In clash of clans, there are some special offers, with 4X, 5X, 6X VALUE! in top as you can see in the picture.

Does this mean for example if we took **Builder Potion** we can gain 6 x 5 hours which mean **30** hours instead of just **6** hours? or what does mean exactly.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a marketing thing to motivate players to buy the bundle.

You will get what's inside the bundle once. The 'value' is just saying that it's a limited offer that's way more valuable than a regular offer for the same amount of money.

Comment: And they basically say whatever the base value is to begin with, so it is purely a marketing gimmick. If the game uses "Diamonds", then you can say each diamond is normally $5, but now, you get it at a massive discount of 80% off at $1! Forgetting that diamonds are actually worth $0 to begin with(unless governments start allowing you to pay taxes with "diamonds").